# FullCalendar with live event

Tags: fullcalendar, live, jquery

I need to fire FullCalendar on `live()` method. So, I tried this:

```
$('.full-calendar').live('fullCalendar', function(){
    return { header : .... //options here }
});
```

But this doesn't work. Do you think is possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

`fullcalendar` is not a supported event by `.live()`<sup>[**ref**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)</sup>. Actually, this **is not an event at all** (unless you created it by yourself but it wouldn't then be supported by `.live()`.

Your full calendar creation must be triggered by a *real* event (click, double-click,...)

You could probably use something like:

```
$('.full-calendar').live('click', function() {
   $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // put your options and callbacks here
    })
});
```